# 3D Rep-tiles and Irreptiles

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, fractals, tiling

There are various known [3D Rep-Tiles and Irreptiles](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/3DRepTilesAndIrreptiles/).  Almost all of them are based on polycubes OR  2D reptiles.  What are the 3D rep-tiles and irreptiles **not** based on polycubes and 2D reptiles?

One infinite set uses $n$ bricks of size $(r^0,r^1,r^2)$ where $r=\sqrt[3]{n}$.  The [Delian Brick](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2822566/) uses two bricks based on the [Delian constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DelianConstant.html).

[image: Delian Brick]

The first to use the Delian brick may have been Thickfun and Dale Walton, who expanded this into the Fifth Chair puzzle, a 4-irreptile.

[image: Fifth chair]

Of the [five space-filling tetrahedra](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SpaceFillingTetrahedra/), at least two are 8-reptiles.

[image: tetrahedron reptiles]

I've put together [code for all of these](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1368091).  Are there any other 3D shapes which can be self-divided into smaller similar shapes, where the underlying shape is not a 2D reptile or a polycube?

Comment: There is a general technique for constructing self-similar tiles in $\mathbb R^n$ using an expansive $n\times n$ integer matrix described in [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2048752) and implemented in Mathematica [in the last print edition of *The Mathematica Journal*](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/2009/01/generating-self-affine-tiles-and-their-boundaries/). While all the examples in those papers are in $\mathbb R^2$, it certainly works in dimension $n$.

Comment: In the ArXiv preprint entitled *Three-Dimensional Rep-Tiles* (2021) by Ryan Blair, Zoe Marley, and Ilianna Richards, all 3D rep-tiles up to homeomorphism are classified. Unfortunately, their approach also relies on polycubes.