# Polyhedra which can be perfectly split into self-similar pieces

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, packing-problem

A cube can be perfectly split into smaller equally sized cubes.  Similarly, a triangular prism can be perfectly split into smaller equally sized triangular prisms.

Is there a name for or list of the set of polyhedra which can be split into smaller self-similar pieces?

Comment: If the pieces have to be similar to the original, then the polygons with the property are called [rep-tiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rep-tile). So far as I know, polyhedra with this property are just get a "3D" qualifier; see, for instance, the question ["3D Rep-tiles and Irreptiles"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2839754/409).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find some non-trivial examples on my page
[Polyhedron rep-tiles (rep-8)](https://ifstile.com/x3d/)
Actually, there are thousands of such polyhedrons even for 8 equal pieces.

Comment: Very cool page!